# Trouble converting a nested if into if(condition1 || condition2)

Tags: c, if-statement, strcmp

I have the following code which functions correctly.

```
if((strcmppgm2ram((char*)name, (ROM char*)"products.htm") != 0))
{
    if((strcmppgm2ram((char*)name, (ROM char*)"restock.htm") != 0))
    {
        return HTTP_IO_DONE;
    }
}
```

I'd like to clean it up and put it in the form:

```
if((strcmppgm2ram((char*)name, (ROM char*)"products.htm") != 0) || (strcmppgm2ram((char*)name, (ROM char*)"restock.htm") !=0))
{   
        return HTTP_IO_DONE;    
}
```

Unfortunately, the latter is not working correctly.  What have I overlooked??  Thanks in advance!
P.S.  strcmp == strcmppgm2ram for the sake of this question.

Comment: Where is strcmppgm2ram() from it is not C

Comment: Yeah sorry Adrian, it's from a Microchip library. Just treat it as strcmp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `||` when you should be using `&&`.

The result should only be reached if BOTH conditions are true.

The reason it didn't work before is because even if one of the strings matched, the other one wouldn't, so regardless of input the statement would always result in returning `HTTP_IO_DONE`.

Comment: Thanks mang, you nailed it! If i'm making logic mistakes that silly it's time to take a break. ;p

Comment: Haha yep...  have a sleep, a coffee or go for a run around the block =)  I challenge you to do any two of those simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you only `return HTTP_IO_DONE;` if **both** conditions turned to be true, therefore you should use **and** (&&) and not **or**

Comment: thanks man... +1 for ya, I have to give answer cred to paddy though as he got it first.  thx again !